# Как создать DataTable каждый раз когда меняется значение атрибута в xml файле или как мне посчитать количество точек в каждом теге file

Tags: c#

Вот пример для одного DataTable, а мне надо сделать лист DataTable - ов, когда меняется значение аттрибута path. А пока у меня все точки записывает в один DataTable

```cs
private DataTable TablePoint()
{
    //создаём таблицу
    DataTable dtPoint = new DataTable();

    //создаём три колонки
    DataColumn x = new DataColumn("x", typeof(Double));
    DataColumn y = new DataColumn("y", typeof(Double));

    //добавляем колонки в таблицу
    dtPoint.Columns.Add(x);
    dtPoint.Columns.Add(y);

    return dtPoint;
}
```

```cs
listDt.Add(TablePoint());
DataRow newRowListDt = null;

foreach (XElement elm in xDoc.Descendants("point"))
{
    newRowListDt = listDt[0].NewRow();

    if (elm.Element("x") != null)
    {
        newRowListDt["x"] = double.Parse(elm.Element("x").Value);
    }

    if (elm.Element("y") != null)
    {
        newRowListDt["y"] = double.Parse(elm.Element("y").Value);
    }
    listDt[0].Rows.Add(newRowListDt);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Xml можно загрузить в DataSet.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("c:\\data.xml");
```

Все point'ы будут доступны в таблице

```
var dt = ds.Tables["point"];
```

Если надо отслеживать изменения в файле `c:\data.xml`, то для этого можно использовать [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).